# Theorem on BFS $X$ and space C of continuous functions in $[0,1]$ and cartesian square of $[0,1]$($[0,1]^2$).

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

This is the definition which we need for the proof of the theorem:
[image]

There is the theorem
Let $X$ be a BFS on $I$. The space $C(I)$ of continuous functions on $I$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$ if and only if there exists a positive constant $c$ satisfying

$||\chi_{(a,b)}||_X$ $\geq$ $c$ whenever $0$ $\leq$ $a$ $\lt$ $b$ $\leq$ $1$. (Mark this condition by ($\star$)).

There is the proof:

For sufficiency part it is enough to show that there is a positive constant $C$ such that for every $f$ $\in$ $C(I)$,

$C$$||f||_{C(I)}$ $\leq$ $||f||_X$ $\leq$ $||f||_{C(I)}$. (Mark this by ($\oplus$)).

The second of these inequalities is clear. For the first, let $f$ $\in$ $C(I)$.

There exists $x_0$ $\in$ $I$ such that $||f||_{C(I)}$ $=$ $|f(x_0)|$; there exists $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$ such that $|f(x_0)|$ $\leq$ $2|f(x)| $if $x$ $\in$ $(x_0 - \epsilon,x_0 + \epsilon)$ $\cap$ $I$ : $=$ $E$.

Thus from $(\star)$ we see that

$||f||_{C(I)}$ $=$ $|f(x_0)|$ $\leq$ $\frac {1}{c}$$|f(x_0)|$$||\chi_E||_X$ $\leq$ $\frac {2}{c}$$||f\chi_E||_X$ $\leq$ $\frac {2}{c}$ $||f||_X$.

Necessity. If $C(I)$ is a closed subset of $X$, then by the closed graph theorem(there it is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis), we have the estimate $(\oplus)$. Let given any interval $(a,b)$ $\subset$ $I$ be given, if we take a continuous function $g$ on $I$ such that $g$ $\leq$ $\chi_{(a,b)}$ and $||g||_L^{\infty}$ $=$ $1$ we get $(\star)$.

There is my question:

This theorem is on $X$ BFS on $[0,1]$ and on  $C([0,1])$ space of continuous functions.
How could we proof that if this theorem is fair or false for $X$ BFS on $[0,1]^2$ ( Cartesian product) and on $C([0,1]^2)$ space of continuous functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First you have to formulate the corresponding theorem: Replace $\chi_{(a,b)}$ by $\chi_{(a,b)\times (c,d)}=\chi_{(a,b)}\otimes \chi_{(c,d)}$.

Comment: @Jochen what do you mean with this sign? ( I mean on the right side. i don’t know how to write it) Is it cartesian product?

Comment: It is the *tensor product* $(f\otimes g)(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ (the LaTeX command is \otimes).

Comment: @Jochen I set bounty on it.

Comment: Where do you get stuck when trying to do the same proof with indicator functions of intervals replaced by indicator functions of rectangles?

Comment: @Jochen how norms will be defined in two dimensions?

Comment: @Jochen could you please write the proof ? I will give you bounty

Comment: The norm for $f\in C([01]^2)$ is, of course, $\|f\|=\sup\{|f(x,y)\|: (x,y)\in [0,1]^2\}$. You are now dealing with a BFS on $\Omega=[0,1]^2$. If you have specific questions, go ahead and ask them. But I will not do **your work**.

Comment: @Jochen I want to know if i should take into the consideration some different structure for the proof.

Comment: No, the proof should be **very** similar.